# How to disable force disconnect of this user on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

Is there any way to disable the "force disconnect of this user" checkbox on Windows Server 2008 R2?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only by making sure that the user logging into the system is not a member of the Administrators group on the local system. Non-administrators will not see the Force disconnect option

Comment: AND: Non-Administrators can not log into a server at all per default policy. That simple. Vicious circle - the request is not sensibible from a design point of view.

Comment: So basically, I'm ****** up, right? :(

Comment: @balizeiro on non-Domain Controllers you can still let non-admins lot in with RDP, just add them to the Remote Desktop Users group

Comment: The problem is that there's only one local admin user that everyone uses

Comment: @balizeiro Everyone using the (same) admin account is certainly a problem. One you should start correcting *yesterday*. You would generally not want to disable the ability for an admin to force-disconnect other users to free up a RDP session (if you need to log in to fix something and all the connections are used by people idling or whose connection died & hasn't been closed yet you want to be able to kick those people off to get your session...)

Comment: This is our development server, where we have 6 people that do installs for the different products, so we didn't saw any problem having only one user.